# Assign the number of ways to share 16 identical objects

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, combinatorics, generating-functions, multinomial-coefficients

In how many different ways can be shared 16 identical objects to 7 different persons such that 3 of them can accept maximum of 2 objects, 3 of them at least 2 objects and for the other person don't have restriction.
I don'n know if I'm on the right way but I started like this: 
f(x)= (1+x+x^2)^3 (x^2+x^3+...+x^16)^3 (1+x+x^2+x^3+...+x^16) then the number of ways is the coefficient of x^16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just give two to each of the three that needs at least two, then distribute the remaining $10$ to ease the restrictions.  That removes the overall factor $x^6$ from your expression.  Your approach is fine, but this makes the maximum  exponent $10$ which simplifies things a bit.  You can also extend the sums to infinity because powers above $10$ will not matter.  Then you get $(1+x+x^2)^3(\frac 1{1-x})^4$ and you are looking for the coefficient of $x^{10}$.  [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%20Expand%20%281%2Bx%2Bx%5E2%29%5E3%281-x%29%5E-4%20near%200) says the answer is $3483$.  You may have to click on More Terms to see it.

Comment: Thank you sooo much i just checked  in Alpha my expand too it says 3483!!! thank youuuu